# Unable to connect to my remote MySql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I try to connect to remote MySQL Server but the server response object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types even I did not pull any data from the server. Remote server is hostinger.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class MySQLConnect

Dim cn As New MySqlConnection("server=myremoteserver; port=myremoteport; user=mydb_user;password=myDbPassword; database=myremoteDb;")

Private cmd As New MySqlCommand   
Private cmd As New MySqlCommand
Private dr As MySqlDataReader

   
If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()

cn.Open()
MessageBox.Show("Connected")

Catch xrr As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(Err.Description, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

But it replies object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types, but if I connect to my local MySql server, it will connect successfully

Comment: Don't type your code — always copy and paste.  `xrr` is not the same as `Err`

Comment: that is not the problem sir, the xrr and err, the problem is object cannot be cast from DBNull when connecting to remote server or live server

Comment: also, yes, i copy and paste the code and also indented of 4 spaces every line. i would like to clarify the issue, the server replies object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types even though there is no pulling of data from the server, just an opening of the connection. i hope it would be clear

Comment: Then maybe you should look at what the `xrr` message is instead of ignoring it.

Comment: i'd already changed sir but still the problem persist

MessageBox.Show(xrr.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

Comment: the problem was resolve. i transfer the server to another server and work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

My problem was ressolve. I transfer the server to another server or from different location and it works like a charm

Comment: this isn't an answer but a comment... please provide specific details and codes as needed to get it qualified as an answer...

Comment: so, i will post the code how i transfer my server from one server to another server?., so here it is. on cPanel, I click the transfer server, then i select a list of server from my hosting server, then the hosting server start to transfer my old server to new selected server and about the code, I dont know what is the code of my hosting server how they transfer my old server to new server